# How to use NetLimiter API in Python?

Tags: python, windows, api

I want to incorporate NetLimiter into my Python program using NetLimiter API. But I haven't found any docs about the API. I have found [this link](https://github.com/LocktimeSoftware/NetLimiterApiSamples) only which doesn't provide any sample program or docs on how to use it.

Does anyone know how to use NetLimiter API in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you need to install **netifaces** library in python,

Here is the damo i have made

```html
import netifaces
import requests

ip_address = netifaces.ifaddresses('eth0')[netifaces.AF_INET][0]['addr']

#Get the IP address of the machine where NetLimiter is installed and port
 
api_url = f'http://{your_ip_address}:8282/nlapi/v1/'


def send_request(method, endpoint, data=None):
    url = api_url + endpoint
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
    response = requests.request(method, url, headers=headers, json=data)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        return response.json()
    else:
        raise Exception(response.text)
enter code here

rules = send_request('GET', 'rules')
print(rules)



rule_data = {
    'name': 'My Rule',
    'direction': 'In',
    'protocol': 'TCP',
    'remoteAddress': '192.168.1.1',
    'remotePort': '80',
    'limit': 1024
}
response = send_request('POST', 'rules', rule_data)
print(response)
```

Comment: I am getting an error. It is saying no connection could me made because the target machine actively refused it.

Comment: please check that you have given the necessary permissions to access network interfaces on your system.

Comment: Yes, I was running the script as an administrator.

Comment: ok do one thing verify these points 
1. Ensure the NetLimiter service runs on the server machine.
2. Check the IP address and port.
3. Check for firewalls and antivirus software
4. Check for network issues